# Polygons from my KML data not showing up in my IOS 6 map application

Tags: objective-c, ios6, mkmapview, kml

I am building an app that has a MKMapview. The view that my code is in extends MKMapView.

After I get data I create a KMLParser and have it parse my KML file witch seems to work just fine. I got the code for my KMLParser via an example from apples developer documentation here http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/KMLViewer/Introduction/Intro.html

Like I said the code seems to work. Some of my KML files only load a Marker onto the map and they work just fine. It's the KML files that need to draw polygon overlays that don't seem to be rendering. I'm wondering if my MKMapViewDelegate code near the bottom isn't doing what it needs to do? I put break points there and they never seem to get hit.

Here is what my view .h and .m look like.

.h

```
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>
#import "MainDM.h"
#import "BBView.h"
#import "MapPM.h"
#import "KMLParser.h"

@class MapPM;
@class MainDM;

@interface MapView : MKMapView <BBView, MKMapViewDelegate>
{
    NSArray *overlays;
    KMLParser *parser;
}

@property(nonatomic,strong)MainDM* dm;
@property(nonatomic,strong)MapPM* pm;
-(void)update:(DataObject*)data;
-(id)initWithModel:(MainDM*)dm:(CGRect)frame;
@end
```

.m

```
#import "MapView.h"

@implementation MapView

-(id)initWithModel:(MainDM*)dm:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self)
    {
        _dm = dm;
        [_dm register:self];
        _pm = [[MapPM alloc] initWithModel:_dm];

        CLLocationCoordinate2D coord = {.latitude =  32.61724, .longitude =  -106.74128};
        MKCoordinateSpan span = {.latitudeDelta =  1, .longitudeDelta =  1};
        MKCoordinateRegion region = {coord, span};

        [self setRegion:region];
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)update:(DataObject*)data
{
    if([[data getType] isEqualToString:@"CURRENT_KML_CHANGE"])
    {
        KmlVO *d = (KmlVO*)[data getData];
        parser = [_pm showMKL:d];

        // Add all of the MKOverlay objects parsed from the KML file to the map.
        NSArray *o = [parser overlays];
        [self addOverlays:o];

        // Add all of the MKAnnotation objects parsed from the KML file to the map.
        NSArray *annotations = [parser points];
        [self addAnnotations:annotations];

        // Walk the list of overlays and annotations and create a MKMapRect that
        // bounds all of them and store it into flyTo.
        MKMapRect flyTo = MKMapRectNull;
        for (id <MKOverlay> overlay in o)
        {
            if (MKMapRectIsNull(flyTo))
            {
                flyTo = [overlay boundingMapRect];
            }
            else
            {
                flyTo = MKMapRectUnion(flyTo, [overlay boundingMapRect]);
            }
        }

        for (id <MKAnnotation> annotation in annotations)
        {
            MKMapPoint annotationPoint = MKMapPointForCoordinate(annotation.coordinate);
            MKMapRect pointRect = MKMapRectMake(annotationPoint.x, annotationPoint.y, 0, 0);
            if (MKMapRectIsNull(flyTo))
            {
                flyTo = pointRect;
            }
            else
            {
                flyTo = MKMapRectUnion(flyTo, pointRect);
            }
        }

        // Position the map so that all overlays and annotations are visible on screen.
        //self.visibleMapRect = flyTo;

    }
}


#pragma mark MKMapViewDelegate

- (MKOverlayView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForOverlay:(id <MKOverlay>)overlay
{

    return [parser viewForOverlay:overlay];
}

- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation
{

    return [parser viewForAnnotation:annotation];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that I was not telling the view to be the delegate so the code at the bottom that draws the polygon layer was not running.

I simply added the following to my initWithModel function

```
self.delegate = self;
```